# Using a value from a previous row to calculate a value in the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a report that pulls the date from a previous row, does some calculation and then displays the answer on the row below that row. The column in question is "Time Spent".

E.g. I have 3 rows.

```
+=====+===============+============+====+
|name |  DatCompleted | Time Spent | idx|
+=====+===============+============+====+
|  A  |    1/1/17     | NULL       | 0  |
+-----+---------------+------------+----+
|  B  |    11/1/17    | 10 days    | 1  |
+-----+---------------+------------+----+
|  C  |    20/1/17    | 9 days     | 2  |
+=====+===============+============+====+
```

Time Spent C = DatCompleted of C - DateCompleted of B

Apart from using a crazy loop and using row x row instead of set I can't see how I would complete this. Has anyone ever used this logic before in SQL? If how did you go about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the `lag()` function:

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `LAG()` function.  Date functions differ depending on the database, but something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (DateCompleted - lag(DateCompleted) over (order by DateCompleted)) as TimeSpent
from t;
```

In SQL Server, you would use `datediff()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day,
                lag(DateCompleted) over (order by DateCompleted), 
                DateCompleted
               ) as TimeSpent
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using ROW number syntax is

```
ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( [ PARTITION BY value_expression , ... [ n ] ] order_by_clause)
```

For reference you can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-use-values-from-previous-or-next-rows-in-a-query-in-sql-server/)

Comment: can you please give example for given problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have an index already (similar to rownumber above). Join to itself.

```
Select table1.*
   ,TimeSpent=DateDiff("d",table1.DateCompleted,copy.DateCompleted)
from table1
   join table1 copy on table.idx=copy.idx-1
```